# Android Listview: getView called for every position at start

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a `Listview` that has around 10 cells which all have a custom layout.
That's why I have a `itemVIewCount` of 10 because I can't recycle views as all cells are different.

The problem that I have is that `getView` is called for every position when I set the `adapter` of my `listview`, not only for the visible ones. Additionally I am not able to scroll in the `listVIew`, I only see the top 3 cells.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView != null) {
        //recycled view is unique, so it is correct
        return convertView;
    }

    return preLoadedViews.get(position);
}
```

Comment: could you post your code please?

Comment: you should post your xml as well for that view, sounds like maybe your listview is larger than the visible screen, but that is just a guess without seeing actual code.

Comment: Problem is that I have to do everything programatically, so no  XML files. THe tableLayout isn't too big, I checked it in the hierarchyviewer: The invisible cells are outside the visible area below the tableView.

Comment: "I have a Listview that has around 10 cells which all have a custom layout" -- then why are you using a `ListView` instead of a vertical `LinearLayout` wrapped in a `ScrollView`? "Problem is that I have to do everything programatically, so no XML files" -- why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question, misread the height of the ListView in the Hierarchyiew. This was indeed the problem, it was set incorrectly.